# Shopify fulfillments/create and fulfillments/update webhook doesn't providing customer phone number

Tags: curl, shopify, webhooks, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am creating application about sending message to customer on various events like order place, order fulfill, fulfillment cancel, refund, order track and order cancel.

I am using webhook for it and i am not getting phone number in fulfillment/create and fulfillment/update webhook.

Kindly make sure that i am getting all data but not only receiving phone number.

This is the code sample

```
<?php
    include("include/connection.php");
    include("variables.php");
    $last_data="SELECT * FROM table_nameORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = $mysql->query($last_data);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $api = "api key";
    $access_token = "access token";
    $webhook_url = "url";
    $webhook_topic = "fulfillments/create";
    $params = array(
        "webhook" => array(
            "topic" => $webhook_topic,
            "address" => $webhook_url,
            "format" => "json"
        ),
    );
    $url = "https://shop_name.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-01/webhooks.json";
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "X-Shopify-Access-Token: {$access_token}",
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    ));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($params));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
?>
```

i am getting access token of my app using select query.